# Javascript to hide the date portion of a date time picker - Only display hours and minutes

Tags: javascript, calendar, datetimepicker, sharepoint-online

Does anyone know of a way I can hide the datepicker portion of a date time field? I want my users to only input an hour & minute.

Is it possible to work it into my current script?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

```
 $(function(){
         setTimeout(function(){
            // checks All Day Event
            if (!$('span[title="All Day Event"] > input').attr("checked")) {
                $('span[title="All Day Event"] > input').click();
            }
            //hide check-box
            $('tr:has(span[title="All Day Event"])').not('tr:has(tr)').hide();
        }, 600);
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is bootstrap-datetimepicker which supports user to select hour and minute only, while you need custom form for CRUD logic.

```
 $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
                        format: 'LT'
                    })
```

You could check below demo thread.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5877444b-98a6-4170-8325-37e1990b6e56/bootstrap-time-picker-validation?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: Thanks Lee, I updated my question. Not sure where I would work that into my current script. Also, am I correct to assume that '#datetimepicker3' should contain the name of my current datetime picker? I.e. '#Arrival/Departure Time'?